# Can I hire people in UK to work for a few days, while I myself being on Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am visiting UK for an exhibition where we are presenting our product. During the exhibition days (2 days), we wish to hire a local UK resident event assistant on an hourly basis for those 2 days. Can we do that? We are registered company in India.

Comment: If you are presenting a product, shouldn't you have a work or business visa yourself?

Comment: The Standard Visitor Visa is both a personal and a business visitor visa, much like a US B1/B2.  To me, at least, this is an interesting question.

Comment: @Neo I suspect this is prohibited under Immigration Rules V4.5 
https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules (c) establishing or running a business as a self-employed person.  
On a practical note, how would you deal with employer responsibilities regarding income tax and National Insurance contributions? In the UK Most people pay Income Tax through PAYE. This is the system employers use to take Income Tax and National Insurance contributions before they pay the employee

Comment: The problem is that if you hire them directly you need to pay national insurance and Income tax (PAYE) on any wages you pay, which in turn requires being registered with HMRC and quite a bit of setup. The alternative is to go through a company which will invoice you and do all that themselves.

Comment: @jcaron I'd guess that all the OP needs to do is to hire someone as a service.  As an analogy there wouldn't be an issue if the OP hired someone to mow a lawn or wash a car.  I'm sure there are staffing agencies that can supply labor.

Comment: Even residents will hire a company or a contractor to provide such services. There are a lot of responsibilities and possible headaches if you hire the person directly.

Comment: @jcaron yes that's what I was thinking. I simply hire a service. We have already screened a candidate who is willing for this, and we verified from her that she is officially allowed to work in UK. In that case, just for 2 days (16 hours) to be precise, do I need to go through PAYE and TAX bits? I mean if I am to hire someone for service can't I just hire her, and then at the end of the event, pay the amount through a Paypal or direct WIRE transfer through her account?

Comment: @Neo you ask for a quote, you sign the contract, she sends you an invoice, you pay and keep and receipt.

Comment: If it’s a service you are buying, you are buying it from someone who is able to invoice you (registered with HMRC etc.). It could be a company, or it could be a single person registered as a “sole trader”. In any case, they send you an invoice and you just pay it, and it’s their responsibility to do all the tax-related stuff. But if you are hiring someone (as an employee), then it’s up to you do to all the tax and social security stuff yourself, which is going to be quite difficult in your case.

Comment: So to clarify, what is important to you is not that the candidate is allowed to work in the UK, but that they are able to invoice you rather than be hired as a employee. This means they must be registered, either as a company (xxx Ltd for instance, with a company registration number you can check on the Companies House website) or a sole trader (not sure if there’s a number for that or a way to check registration, though). Depending on their turnover they may also be registered for VAT (in which case they will also add VAT to the invoice).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help and information so far. It's really helpful. I don't think the person we are planning to hire is registered there. She just has work permit. To avoid this, I am thinking, is it an option, that I simply show her as an internship/unpaid work or even a volunteer who is helping me out? May be an acquaintance? And then I can simply pay her in cash. Anyways this is just for 2 days and I am looking for a simple solution. @jcaron and others, please let me know if this can work.

Comment: This is just plain illegal and can have very serious consequences, so nobody here will tell you this is OK.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I understand. My problem is it's not feasible for me to do the necessary procedures to 'hire' in UK, and I don't want to contact a service provider because there is no time left remaining to do the procedure to select a new candidate as we have invested quite some time training her with the details for the conference. Another things crossing my mind, we do hire a lot of off shore developers through freelancing platforms like freelancer.com and upwork.com. Can I take this contract there? How does that work in UK? Will this route be legal? Again a big thanks to all